# Interactive firewall for limiting outgoing requests

Tags: centos, fedora, firewall

15 years ago I used a product on Windows which would alert me if a **process** was trying to **send traffic outbound** (e.g. use the internet or LAN). I could add rules for defining what was allowed and what wasn't.

**Is there a similar product that I can use with Fedora 25 and Gnome?**

Comment: Try [douane](http://douaneapp.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[Opensnitch](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch) is a set of tools that includes a per-application GUI firewall. You'll need to run two processes: a network daemon process that must be run as root, and a GUI process that runs under the current user.

It is not in standard repos, so you'll have to follow the instructions on the github page.

[image]

> *Looking at the [most active forks of opensnitch](https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html#https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch) shows a couple of forks which are more active than the original opensnitch (for example [gustavo-iniguez-goya's fork](https://github.com/gustavo-iniguez-goya/opensnitch)), so you might want to check those out too.*

Answer (score 1):

I just did it with Tomoyo, and it works great.  It is not exactly interactive, in the sense that I don't get popups to ask me to allow or block processes, but I still get a very granular GUI to selectively allow or block softwares. I wanted to do it with a software that has been approved by the linux community -- I do not have the necessary knowledge to evaluate third party solutions and I wanted to minimize the chances of ending up with a firewall that had vulnerabilities in it. Tomoyo is included in Mint Linux kernel, all you have to do is install the tools for Tomoyo. You can google "how-to-application-oriented-firewall-simple-and-easy-using-tomoyo", the instructions are clear, and Tomoyo is quite user-friendly. The idea is to block everything, except the softwares that you explicitly allow. (In my case I had to allow a few more processes or services apart from my browser, which I found using 'sudo lsof -i' on a VM that had internet access on it ---  etc. I'll have to finetune this, I probably allowed more than necessary). Hope this works for you. (I just hope  Debian is gonna keep including Tomoyo in it's kernel, which seems much more user-friendly than apparmor or selinux, from what I have read. Since you are using Fedora, there are instructions in the document I referenced for arranging to have a kernel that has Tomoyo... Good luck.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason such a thing isn't commonly done in the Unix world. It's because Unix uses a lot of co-operating programs, and Windows really doesn't.

In the Windows world, a program might load a bunch of DLLs to delegate work to libraries, but the application doing things stays the same.

Unix has shared libraries too, but a lot of reuse happens by launching other programs to get stuff done. For example, a lot of programs that download updates and such end up delegating the work to `wget` or `curl`.

Thus, you will end up needing to enable outbound HTTP(S) for `wget` or `curl` just to get software updates for the OS to work. Unfortunately, that pretty much opens up outbound HTTP(S) for everything.

You should thus restrict based on an attribute that can't readily be changed, such as user and group IDs. `iptables` has the `owner` match for this, but it probably isn't supported by a lot of GUI firewalls so you might need to end up writing your own `iptables` rules.

Comment: That's quite scary, because if some rogue keyboard logger is running and delegates to curl, no firewall can stop it uploading collected data. Or could that be done by checking out the parent process? Is there a way to configure iptables to only allow based on parent process name?

Comment: @AntKutschera You can configure iptables to deny by default and only allow processes with a certain GID. Then you can `sudo -g` to that GID when starting the browser or anything that you want to allow Internet access for. I tried this once, but I hit a number of obstacles. For one thing `apt-get` actually sets GID=0 (which makes sense, since it might install system files that should have owner GID 0 rather than some random GID). So I had workarounds for `apt-get` and some other programs but it basically can be done if you have the energy to get it to work.